# Desktop application accessible by multiple users

Tags: vb.net, web, desktop-application

I have a desktop application [Data Analysis and Report Generation] built in VB. I would like to make this application accessible to all the users in our corporation, from their web browsers. What is the best possible way to achieve this?

One way which I have thought is to write a simple web form that would take the input from the user and apply logic on the server and generate results. Again, the limitation would be at the output screen as it is the real time output being generated.

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it WinForm or WPF? You could use a WPF browser application if you are using XAML.

Comment: It is a WinForm. Can you elaborate on XAM ~ WPF browser

Comment: WPF Browser applications are applications that run inside a web browser but are written using desktop technologies like XAML. If rewriting your applications UI is an option then you can probably write your UI using XAML and you must be able to use your business logic as it is. Then Your users can use it using their browsers. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Tanwer, is there anyway possible that I have my current desktop app integrated in XBAP?

Comment: It may be, WPF supports integrating WinForms controls using WindowsFormsHost http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. You can embed your whole screen inside WPF control. If your app has one few screens it may be worth trying. But if you have large number of screens(10-20) It may be a difficult task to host all those in WPF WinFormsHost.

Answer (score 1):

**Desktop App is way different from web app. To allow multiple users, a web app is suitable. For this you will have to use several technologies.**

**The UI** has to be build using html, css and javascript (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)).

**The back end**, can be VB if you are doing working with asp.net or php etc.

**For real time output**, you'll have to use ajax to allow communication between a browser and sever without page refreshes

An ideal choice for the front end logic, would be to use a frontend framework such as [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) by google.

However, all this does have a **high** learning curve and is difficult to build something using all this on the first day or even week unless you already know most of this.

Comment: Thanks @Krimson, my main priority is to consume less time for this and avoid re-writing the application. Is that in any way possible?

Comment: @saadasharif Im sorry to say but I don't know any other way to do it other that doing a rewrite. There are other technologies like WPF as people have mentioned. You could try java applets which is coded just like a desktop app.

Comment: @saadasharif But why do you want it in a web browser? If I were you, I would link the application to an online database and distribute the application. That way many people have the application which all connect to one central database.

Comment: I solved it by building a web service with same functionality and a silverlight based user interface, accessible from web browser. Lot of re-work had to be done but the results are good, meeting the expectations of the users. :)